# Who is the actor in a Use Case Diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

I'm making "UML Use Case" for an application that will have actors:

- user (a normal user),
- `google` (to make OpenID registration).

What will I use: OpenID or Google? What is the *real* actor here? The actor which will make the interaction with the user to be represented in the Use case diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An actor is a person, organization or system that interacts with your system. `OpenID` is none of these. `Google` is. So you should model `Google` as the actor.

Comment: But `OpenID` is not a system, it is a protocol. As you said, if the service is generic one can add an actor named `OpenID Service Provider` and from it inherit `Google OpenID Service Provider`

Comment: i'll stick with this answer, i'll get the Google as an actor :) thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Both are valid choices. If you want to express that Google acts as a company you can add it as an actor. If you want to express that the user interacts with a general "OpenID Service" you can put it there as well. Or you can combine it and name the actor "Google OpenID Service" to make it more specific.

Comment: thank you for the reply, about google openid service, it is general no? since it is not google that provides the initial service?